# Is it possible to search WHOIS data by parameters like zip/postal code?

Tags: domains, whois

Is it possible to search WHOIS data by parameters such as: registrant name, registrant email, registrant zip/postal code?

Comment: Not really. Domaintools.com does give you some of this for a price. Not worth the price though.

Comment: Most Registrar WHOIS searches are limited to just the domain name to prevent  marketing and spamming, as covered under ICANN's [Uses of WHOIS](https://whois.icann.org/en/basics-whois). There are "research"/database sites whom aren't registrars themselves and therefore are not bound by these same terms, such as DomainTools. These provide domain name and registration searches by more criteria, usually on a subscription basis to find out more details.

Comment: As a matter of curiosity, why are you asking? We have gotten this question a few times and I simply do not understand why. Can you fill me into why you are interested in being able to search this way??

Answer (score 2):

No. If you search the [Network Solutions WhoIs database](https://www.networksolutions.com/whois/index.jsp), you only get 2 search options:

- By Domain Name
- By IP Address

If you search for a zip code like: "90210", it will try to lookup "90210.com". It won't search for all domains in the 90210 (Beverly Hills, CA) zip code.